# Arduino Serial and Socket

Tags: node.js, sockets, arduino

I m trying to Send serial data to Arduino using Node.js and Socket.io and my code.

and the html page have only one button. its work node and html side .but this is not send serial data.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
 var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


 server.listen(port, function () {
//  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});

 // Routing

 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var SerialPort = require("serialport").SerialPort
var serialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyACM3", {
baudrate:9600
}, false); // this is the openImmediately flag [default is true]



io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);

        serialPort.open(function () {
            console.log('open');
            serialPort.on('data', function (data) {
                console.log('data received: ' + data);
            });

        serialPort.write(data, function (err, results) {
            console.log('err ' + err);
            console.log('results ' + results);
        });
    });

  });
  });

 app.get('/', function (req, res) {
 res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

Comment: Are any of your console.log statements being fired?  Output would be helpful.

Comment: its give me only   'I received '  its written  in  arduino code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending serial messages to the Arduino is not as easy as simply passing in a String. Unfortunately you have to send the String character by character which the Arduino will receive and concatenate back to a String. After you sent the last character you need to send one final new line character (/n) which is a signal for the Arduino to stop concatenating and evaluate the message.

This is what you need to do in your Node.js server:

```
// Socket.IO message from the browser
socket.on('serialEvent', function (data) {

    // The message received as a String
    console.log(data);

    // Sending String character by character
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        myPort.write(new Buffer(data[i], 'ascii'), function(err, results) {
            // console.log('Error: ' + err);
            // console.log('Results ' + results);
        });
    }

    // Sending the terminate character
    myPort.write(new Buffer('\n', 'ascii'), function(err, results) {
        // console.log('err ' + err);
        // console.log('results ' + results);
    });
});
```

And this is the Arduino code that receives this:

```
String inData = "";

void loop(){
    while (Serial.available() > 0) {
        char received = Serial.read();
        inData.concat(received);

        // Process message when new line character is received
        if (received == '\n') {
            // Message is ready in inDate
        }
    }
}
```